# Apache VirtualHost and Wildcard SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

I am trying to configure my website so that :

- www.example.com alias example.com is served by a VirtualHost
- *.example.com are serverd by another one with different DocumentRoot

My concern is that the first item works well, but if I call site1.example.com, it still shows /home/default_domain content, not /home/blogs/site1

Here is the configuration:

```
Listen 443 https

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/default_domain

    [SSL configuration]

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName blabla.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/blogs/%1

    [SSL configuration]

   <Directory /home/blogs/>
      Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Answering myself: it works fine, there was a type in my configuration file